# pandas.update on Multiindex using single Index

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fill up a DataFrame with a MultiIndex using values from a DataFrame with a simple Index, where the simple Index matches the MultiIndex'es first column. It should not touch anything where there isn't a match. I `tried multiindexed.update(singleindexed, overwrite=False)`, but that didn't work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

products = ['shoes']*5 + ['socks']*5 + ['boots']*5
years = [2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009]*3
values = [11, np.NaN, 12, np.NaN, 7, 23, 8, 40, 5, np.NaN, np.NaN, 53, np.NaN, 88, 34]

df = pd.DataFrame({'product': products, 'year': years, 'value': values})
df = df.set_index(['product', 'year'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'products': ['shoes', 'socks'], 'value': [555555, 666666]})
df1 = df1.set_index('products')
```

The MultiIndex-ed data looks like:

```
               value
product  year    
shoes    2005    11
         2006    NaN
         2007    12
         2008    NaN
         2009    7
socks    2005    23
         2006    8
         2007    40
         2008    5
         2009    NaN
boots    2005    NaN
         2006    53
         2007    NaN
         2008    88
         2009    34
```

The single-Index-ed data looks like

```
product
shoes      555555
socks      666666
```

The result should look like

```
               value
product  year    
shoes    2005    11
         2006    555555
         2007    12
         2008    555555
         2009    7
boots    2005    NaN
         2006    53
         2007    NaN
         2008    88
         2009    34
```

What am I missing here? Is `update` even the right approach, or should I be looking at `apply`?

**Edit** Added the data to generate this example, and added an important omission: I forgot to mention that non-matching values should not be touched, hence I cannot use `fillna()`. `df.update(df1, overwrite=False)` would have seemed like a perfect and simple fit.

Comment: you are looking for `fillna` use it like `df1.fillna(df2.set_index('product'))`

Comment: This would indeed have worked on my original example, but I forgot to mention that it should not touch NaNs that didn't match. Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `reindex` and slice assign

```
df.loc[df.value.isnull(),'value']=df1.reindex(df.index.get_level_values(0))[df.value.isnull().values].values
df
                 value
product year          
shoes   2005      11.0
        2006  555555.0
        2007      12.0
        2008  555555.0
        2009       7.0
socks   2005      23.0
        2006       8.0
        2007      40.0
        2008       5.0
        2009  666666.0
```